# Runtime Error Unfortunately app has stopped?

Tags: android, android-logcat

While trying to run my app on handset, when I am trying to go from one activity to other its throwing error `Unfortunately app has stopped !` & When I checked in Logcat I'm getting following error messages...

```
12-07 03:12:57.958  17518-17518/com.android.mads.madses E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android.mads.madses, PID: 17518
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/TintManager;
            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.<init>(TabLayout.java:1145)
            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:635)
            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTabView(TabLayout.java:669)
            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:365)
            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:340)
            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:624)
            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:595)
            at com.android.mads.madses.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:35)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.mads.madses-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.<init>(TabLayout.java:1145)
            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:635)
            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTabView(TabLayout.java:669)
            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:365)
            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:340)
            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:624)
            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:595)
            at com.android.mads.madses.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:35)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 22 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Can anybody please help?

Code:
**Main RegisterActivity** (Parent Tab Activity)

```
package com.android.mads.madses;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        adapter.addFrag(new LoginInfoFragment(), "LoginInfo");
        adapter.addFrag(new PersonalInfoFragment(), "PersonalInfo");
        adapter.addFrag(new ContactInfoFragment(), "ContactInfo");
        adapter.addFrag(new VechicleInfoFragment(), "VechicleInfo");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }


}
```

One of the **Fragment Activity** (all other fragment have same code)

```
package com.android.mads.madses;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 07-12-2015.
 */
public class VechicleInfoFragment extends Fragment{

    public VechicleInfoFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vechicleinfo , container, false);
    }
}
```

**Login Activity** (Here when i click 'Dont have an account? Signup here' app stopped)

```
package com.android.mads.madses;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.mads.app.AppConfig;
import com.android.mads.app.AppController;
import com.android.mads.helper.SQLiteHandler;
import com.android.mads.helper.SessionManager;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText ed_email, ed_password;
    private Button btn_login, btn_newUser;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    private static final String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        ed_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtxt_login_email);
        ed_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtxt_login_password);
        btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btn_newUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login_newUser);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = ed_email.getText().toString();
                String password = ed_password.getText().toString();

                if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please Enter Details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                } else {
                    checkLogin(email, password);
                }
            }
        });

        btn_newUser.setPaintFlags(btn_newUser.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
        btn_newUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    public void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
        String tag_req = "login_request";
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging In...");
        showDialog();

        final StringRequest strR = new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.LOGIN_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        hideDialog();

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsb = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean error = jsb.getBoolean("error");
                            if (!error) {
                                String uid = jsb.getString("uid");

                                JSONObject user = jsb.getJSONObject("user");
                                String fname = user.getString("fname");
                                String lname = user.getString("lname");
                                String email = user.getString("email");
                                String dob = user.getString("dob");
                                String address = user.getString("address");
                                String bloodgroup = user.getString("bloodgroup");
                                String contact1 = user.getString("contact1");
                                String contact2 = user.getString("contact2");
                                String vechiclename = user.getString("vechiclename");
                                String fueltype = user.getString("fueltype");
                                String mileage = user.getString("mileage");
                                String created_at = user.getString("created_at");
                                db.addUser(uid, fname, lname, email, dob,
                                        address, bloodgroup, contact1, contact2,
                                        vechiclename, fueltype, mileage, created_at);

                                session.setLogin(true);

                                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                String error_msg = jsb.getString("error_msg");
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, error_msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("TAG ", error.getMessage());
                    }
                }
        ) {
            public Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> p = new HashMap<String, String>();
                p.put("tag", "login");
                p.put("email", email);
                p.put("password", password);

                return p;
            }
        };

        AppController.getmInstance().addToRequestQueue(strR, tag_req);

    }

    public void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.show();
        }
    }

    public void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.mads.madses"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile project (":volley")
}
```

Comment: can you please show your code

Comment: and post your build.gradle

Comment: Enabled `ProGuard` ahh ?

Comment: Please check the code.

Comment: Don't know how but it started working properly now.

Comment: Even am struggling with the same issue since yesterday, if you solved it please tell me how.

Comment: Looks like you are missing the v7 support library, but i can see you import it on gradle.... Try clean and build

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i downgraded appcompat-v7 from:

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

to:

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'

and it worked.

Comment: in my case i will change                                                                                   compileSdkVersion 24                                                                                and all dependencies                                                                                compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'

Answer (score 2):

changing dependencies will surely solve the problem , just added

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
```

and updated build tools version to 23.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar exception after updating android studio to 2.0. 
I'm using design library to load tabs and I got exception when I was opening the activity. So I did the following to fix issues.

I updated 
Android SDK tools 
Android SDK Platform tools 
Android SDK build tools 
Android Support library

to latest available versions and I set the following as 
 compileSdkVersion 23 
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

and 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

It fixed my issue.

Answer (score -1):

Here the steps you need to take to solve this problem

1. Check your `compileSdkVersion` version in app level gradle file[In my case its 23]
2. Check your dependencies in same file and make sure that the version of your appcompat and design must start from same number as 
   `compileSdkVersion`
3. Append the version of dependencies with '+' like [this](https://gyazo.com/5990d17587762acc98650628daa3e040)